# Use the class in several projects (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am going  to use one class in several Android projects. After importing namespace of the class the second app became being installed with the parent app.
Is there a way to prevent such behavior? How should I set up projects in Eclipse?

Comment: I dont think Eclipse does that automatically for you but I think what you are looking for is library projects. not really sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all the code you need in multiple apps into a separate project, and mark it as a Library Project by right clicking on the project, going to `Properties -> Android` and checking the `Is Library` option.

Then simply include it as a Library in your other projects.

Comment: I've created Library Project and marked it as a required project in build path but still getting NoClassDefFoundError. The same happens when I add JAR-file in Library Project's bin folder to the build path. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So the complete answer is the following:
1) The class should be put to a separete project which should be marked as a Library Project.
2) To use the class in other projects the created library should be choosed in `Properties -> Android` as described here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject